# Why Dependency injection of a factory inside another factory failing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I have one factory like this :

```
    app.factory('LoginFactory', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        var urlBase = "http://localhost:8080/app";
        var fact = {};
        fact.login = function(userinfo) {
            return $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : urlBase + '/login',
                data : userinfo,
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                    'Accept' : 'application/json'
                }
            });
        };
        fact.validate = function(sessionId) {
            return $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : urlBase + '/validate?sessionId=' + sessionId,
            });
        };
        return fact;
    } ]);
```

And Another factory like this :

```
    app.factory('LoginService', [
            'Credentials',
            function(Credentials, $location, LoginFactory) {
                var fact = {};
                fact.isLoggedin = function() {
                    var result = false;
                    LoginFactory.validate(Credentials.sessionId).success(
                            function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                result = true;
                            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        result = false;
                    });
                    return result;
                };
                fact.authenticate = function(userinfo) {
                    LoginFactory.login(userinfo).success(
                            function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                Credentials = data;
                                $location.path('/home');
                            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    });
                };
                return fact;
            } ]);
```

In the Browser Console I am getting the following error :

Error: LoginFactory is undefined

Can anyone please help me out with this error.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring your service using the array notation, taking the names of the dependencies to inject followed by the function defining the factory. But you said you only wanted to inject Credentials:

```
app.factory('LoginService', [
        'Credentials',
        function(Credentials, $location, LoginFactory) {
```

So angular only injects Credentials. The above should be replaced by

```
app.factory('LoginService', [
        'Credentials', '$location', 'LoginFactory'
        function(Credentials, $location, LoginFactory) {
```

To avoid those bugs, and the repetition of service names in the array and in the function, I strongly suggest using [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) in your build.

Comment: Hi,I have made the change what you have given, and I got the error
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20LoginFactory%20%3C-%20LoginService
This error message comes when spelling mistake is there, I don't see any spelling mistake in my code.
app.factory('LoginService', ['Credentials', '$location','LoginFactory', function(Credentials, $location, LoginFactory) {

Comment: You're trying to inject a $scope into a service. That's not possible. Only controllers can have a scope. The only scope injectable into a service is the $rootScope.